# k mount lens to a 58mm thread camera

Tags: lens, pentax, old-lenses, lens-adapter, k-mount

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use Pentax lenses on a Lumix FZ18?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27965/how-can-i-use-pentax-lenses-on-a-lumix-fz18)

I found this 3 old lenses from a ricoh kr10 camera which I really liked a lot. The problem is that that camera doesnt work anymore and I would still like to use those lenses on my other camera, Kodak p850, which I have adjusted to have a thread size of 58mm. The lenses are k mount and I was wondering if there is some kind of adapter ring or something to mount this k mount lenses to my 58mm camera?

Comment: What do you mean by 58mm thread size camera? Usually thread size is a property of the lens.

Comment: well I had to buy an adapter for my camera in order to use my 58mm filters.

Comment: In essence this is the same as [How can I use Pentax lenses on a Lumix FZ18?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27965/how-can-i-use-pentax-lenses-on-a-lumix-fz18). My answer there basically applies: this is a point and shoot camera not designed for interchangeable lenses, and there's no reasonable way to make it work like you're hoping.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: your camera isn't designed to change lenses and no effort you make is going to change that fact. If you want to change lenses, then you need an SLR or similar camera that designed with this in mind.

As a side note, the old Ricoh K-mount isn't actually compatible with Pentax cameras, so be careful trying to do so if you decide to upgrade. Google the term "ricoh pin" for details.