# Did I get ripped off by purchasing a "deluxe bundle" with my camera?

Tags: lens, canon, equipment-recommendation, accessories

Let me start by saying I'm a newbie to photography and appreciate all help! I purchased a camera "package" on Amazon. 
This 33rd Street Deluxe Bundle Includes :
Canon EOS Rebel T5i DSLR Camera with Canon EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS STM Lens.

- 2.2x HD AF Telephoto Lens
- 0.43x HD AF Wide Angle Lens

There were other standard items included but I'm concerned about these two add-on lenses. I can't figure out how to attach them. My book says EF lenses and these are AF lenses. Did I purchase lenses that won't work on my camera? I really need to know quick so I can return the package if they can't be used. Again, any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Those are not lenses, they are accessory optics. The seller is trying to trick you.

Comment: Wow, "HD AF" kind of tripped me up while reading...

Comment: I agree that it's deceitful, but they technically *are* lenses.

Comment: And they are kind of fun to use - but best bought as surplus/used goods.

Answer (score 18):

> I really need to know quick so I can return the package if they can't be used.

I don't think you got ripped off, exactly. If the bundle you bought cost about the same as the T5i kit sold by Canon, then you're fine. 3rd party sellers often try to sweeten the deal to attract your business by throwing in a bunch of extras; if you never use them but they didn't cost you anything extra, then there's no real harm: you still got the same camera and lens, same warranty, etc. And if the bundle included any thing extra that you *do* use, then you're a little ahead of the game.

On the other hand, if you thought you were buying a camera body and three lenses and instead got one lens and two "filter lenses," then you didn't get what you expected. If you paid a significantly higher price for the bundle than the normal price of the kit, returning would make sense. If you paid about the same as the kit price, then returning and getting the kit from Canon might not make much sense.

Answer (score 11):

Those 'AF' lenses attach to the front of the 18-55 EF-S lens, not directly to the camera.  They modify the behaviour of the original lens.

They are not true wide angle or telephoto lenses, they're modifiers.  I've never used them and can't comment on whether they are any use, or any good, but they should at least fit.

There's more information in [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/17591/what-is-a-2-2x-pro-telephoto-lens).

I would question whether you're getting value from all the added components - those two lens modifiers for example are probably very low quality and you might get very little value from them.

Comment: Thanks for the input! I'm going to send the whole package back and just start from scratch and build my kit. I really like the camera! I'm traveling to Scotland for two weeks in October. I need a good camera to capture the memories. Suggestions?

Comment: That's a complex question.  My suggestion is buy the Canon + EF-S 18-55mm that you mentioned above, from Amazon, making sure it's from just Amazon and is the official 'kit'.  You'll need to buy memory card separately.  Then spend a few weeks getting used to it, shooting lots and lots and lots, and then decide if there's something else you need.  Enjoy!

Comment: Agree, except for the part about inflating the price. There are a number of 3rd party T5i bundles that sell on Amazon for $649 (right now, anyway), which is the same price as the camera kit (body and lens) from Canon. The other items are thrown in to make the bundles more attractive and draw your business. An alternative would be to leave the extras out but sell at a lower price, but retailers are probably prohibited from undercutting Canon.

Comment: Weirdly, this seems to be an amazon.com phenomenon, you can't get anything like those bundles on the UK amazon site, which is why I was first surprised to see them.  But yes, you're correct - the price appears to match the straight camera kit price too.

Comment: The thing you must be careful about with the 3rd party "deals" that match the price of the official "Canon kit" is are you getting the OEM accessories, such as batteries, chargers, and even mundane things such as camera straps and lens caps? Or is the seller swapping the OEM battery, charger, and other accessories for cheap third party ones? Also, is the 3rd party deal a U.S. warranty or an "international" gray market unit that carries no U.S. warranty (assuming you are in the U.S. serviced by amazon.com)?

Answer (score 6):

These are add-on lenses that mount to the front of your 18-55 allowing for wider or narrower view at the expense of optical quality and practicality.

Your de luxe package contains lots of the lowest quality junk that you will probably find useless or inferior.

If you can still revert your purchasing decision, I'd suggest that you buy just the camera body and the 18-55mm lens from a reputable dealer and get any other equipment when and if you really need it and select products of reasonable quality.