# Is the zoom (18-55mm) of my Nikon D3000 broken?

Tags: troubleshooting, zoom, nikon-d3000

I've been having troubles with the zoom of the camera. I can only set the level from 18 to 24 when I used to be able to choose what ever value I wanted (between 18 and 55mm of course!!). The 'zoom wheel' just stops when it reaches 24mm. I don't know if I unintentionally set the camera for this strange function or the zoom is broken. Thank you all!!!

Comment: from what i understand, the zoom ring is 100% mechanical. this means it is physically stuck at 24mm. Perhaps some grit/sand like mattdm suggested. It is usually not worth fixing a kit lens. Maybe upgrading is a good idea if you can afford it. Nevertheless, if they don't charge you inspection fee, send it in to see what the problem is.

Comment: Okay, I'll take the camera to the store and see what they can do!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

The zoom on this lens (as with most DSLR lenses) is manual, so there's no settings to control. Sounds like it's broken -- possibly a small bit of grit in the mechanism.

You could probably get it repaired cheaply (and it'd probably be done under warranty for free, as long as you haven't been rolling around in the sand dunes with it, and of course if your warranty still applies), but you might want to take it as an excuse to upgrade [beyond the kit lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8467/what-are-the-limitations-of-a-typical-kit-lens-as-a-general-purpose-lens).

Comment: I hope you're right, I bought the camera recently so the warranty should be still fine. I'll see what the store has to say about it! Thank you!