# D7000 Kit (18-55mm) or D7000 Kit (18-105)? or should I get a separate lens?

Tags: lens, equipment-recommendation, nikon, nikon-d7000, kit-lens

I'm no expert on cameras and lenses. Can you give me some pieces of advise on what to choose?

If I buy the body and separate lens, what should I buy for a general purpose lens.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I saw that sir but isn't that specific?

Comment: What kind of pictures do you want to take? What lens is best always depends on the photograph you want to make.

Comment: General purpose lens sir. More on streets, nature, and people or something like that. Seldom on low light.

Comment: You might find [What are the limitations of the kit lens as a general purpose lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/8467/) (and other questions under the [tag:kit-lens] tag) to help you figure out whether one of those kit lenses will serve as general purpose for you.

Comment: Are there any previous questions that directly compare these two lenses or current Nikon kit lenses in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 18-105 is a better lens.  Sharper wide open.  It also gives you more zoom range, obviously.

18-55mm is a good range for everyday snap shots, but the 55-105mm range that the 18-105mm gives you in addition, is a good range for portraits.

The 18-105mm costs more.  Whether it is worth the extra amount depends on you and your budget.

If you buy the 18-55, and at some point you think you are missing out and want a telephoto lens, you'll end up spending the extra money anyway on a 2nd lens like the 55-200mm.

It's a very personal decision, but I think for someone starting out, something like the 18-105, 18-135 or 18-200 is a good choice.  Keeps it simple - you only have one lens to worry about.  If it's stretching your budget, the 18-55 is fine to start out with though - it covers the useful range you'd use for snapshots, street, travel, nature.

Answer (score 0):

For a beginner, the Nikon D7000 kit lens is a decent device; stick to it for starters rather than picking another one.

It used to be the case that the kit lenses were not that good even for the beginners. But, that is not the case for D7000 (I own one along with the kit lens and a high-end F2.8 70-200 VR lens; I still like the kit lens).

Now to compare the two kit lenses in your question.

1. 2179 [AF-S DX NIKKOR 18-105mm f/3.5-5.6G ED VR](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2179/AF-S-DX-NIKKOR-18-105mm-f%252F3.5-5.6G-ED-VR.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-TechSpecs)
   (could not find a reference for this D7000 kit)
2. 2176 [AF-S DX NIKKOR 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G VR](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2176/AF-S-DX-NIKKOR-18-55mm-f%252F3.5-5.6G-VR.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-TechSpecs) -- is this part of the kit?
3. 2170 [AF-S DX Zoom-Nikkor 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6G ED II](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2170/AF-S-DX-Zoom-NIKKOR-18-55mm-f%252F3.5-5.6G-ED-II.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-TechSpecs) -- or, is it this one?
4. 2192 [AF-S DX NIKKOR 18-200mm f/3.5-5.6G ED VR II](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Camera-Lenses/2192/AF-S-DX-NIKKOR-18-200mm-f%252F3.5-5.6G-ED-VR-II.html#tab-ProductDetail-ProductTabs-TechSpecs)  -- also a kit

The 4 digit number at the beginning of each line is the lens model number. It is a good thing to refer with that number (to avoid confusion).

**I would move towards the 18-105**.

I also see a `18-200` lens kit on Amazon but note that it appears like the `2192` model rather than the `2159`, which I think is now not available.

I'll suggest you go to the [NikonUSA search page](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/About-Nikon/Search.page), look for these lenses by their model number and then compare them -- the site supports doing that.

Things that you should consider while making a pick.

1. Are the two kits priced differently?
   The `18-105` model 2179 seems priced $200 above the `18-55` model 2176.
2. Both seem to have `VR` but the `18-105` seems like a better spec'ed one (`IF`, `ED` element, 67mm diameter means wider glass -- more light)